# CKeditor not working for users only in forums

Tags: wysiwyg

I Installed CKeditor in drupal 7, and all works fine, except in the forums. If I enter as an administrator, there CKeditor works just fine (in the administrator overlay) but if I log as a standard user CKeditor works in all areas but the forums, where I get the following error: TypeError: $(...).get(...) is undefined as in the following line of code: $("#node-form").get(0).setAttribute('action', '/?q=node/add/forum/0&29e0_name=0a'+v+'8f52a260a1342d3127_form');

I'm out of ideas and the solutions offered here are usually for CK editor not working in general, but here the frustration is that it only doesn't work in the forums section and only for standard users.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a javascript error. Have you tried installing the `jquery_update` module and evaluating what javascript libraries or drupal modules making use of Javascript are installed on the website and looking for conflicts between the modules.

What javascript file is producing the error. Using Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug for firefox and looking at the Console will give you the filename.